# How do I run a Java thread at an interval and cancel it if it exceeds a time limit?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, cancellation

I'm trying to design a system by which I can have a Thread execute at a certain interval of time (e.g. 10 seconds), and also have it cancelled at a certain time if it overruns a time limit (e.g. 5 seconds). Maybe this isn't the right way to do what i'm looking for but id like some help nonetheless.

I thought about using the `ExectuorService` to perform this, but will I run into problems with it?

Comment: Oracle offers a great documentation on threading.  [Lesson: Concurrency (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).  And, more specifically, _[Executor Interfaces (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

> have a Thread execute at a certain interval of time (e.g. 10 seconds)

**You can.**

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to repeatedly execute a task at a specified period of time.

This has been covered extensively on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

## Forcibly halt a thread

> have it cancelled at a certain time if it overruns a time limit (e.g. 5 seconds).

**You cannot.**

Java provides no way to forcibly halt the execution of a thread.

Java concurrency allows only for cooperative cancellation. You can signal your intention for another thread to halt by “interrupting”. But this interrupt attempt merely sets a flag, and wakes the thread if sleeping. The task must be coded to regularly look for the interrupt flag. If flag is set, the task must be coded to then  end its own execution.

This too has been covered extensively on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Since threading is conceptualized, and not necessarily as procedural as a single-running process, Java utilized the concept of interruptions.  Arguing that, to implement a way to exit a thread mid-execution would, as they state in their [JavaDoc](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L1645), _"... unlock all of the monitors, ... potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior."_.  This is a concept in the theory of threading, and not something specific to Java.  Although, Java requires it.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track; you can definitely do this with ExecutorService. You can use `awaitTermination()` with a timeout, check if the threads have completed with `isTerminated()` (after `shutdown()`), and request to terminate any threads that have not terminated.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: How exactly does one forcibly terminate a thread in Java? That’s news to me.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I believe the recommended approach is to use the _[inturrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())_ call.  [Interrupts (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > Concurrency)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

Comment: @Reilas Yes, but that is *not* forcible termination.

Comment: @Reilas But that doesn’t “forcefully” terminate a thread, in fact, in java, there is no (reliable) way to do so - you need to design for it

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's why it's called _"threading"_.

Comment: @BasilBourque, he's saying to interrupt the threads.  He's not talking about sending a process signal, just a termination of the thread's executing.  I believe the terminology is overlapping here.

Comment: @Reilas The problem is, as consumers of your answer, the term *"forcibly terminate any threads"* is misleading and may lead the OP in the wrong direction - remember, the meaning of communication is down to the interruption of the receiver, not the sender . If we are interrupting your intent incorrect, then developers will less experience will most certainly do so. We're trying to improve your answer - which is why we've not downvoted 

Comment: @Reilas There is no way “to force a termination of the thread's executing” in Java.

Comment: @Reilas You CAN NOT *"forcibly terminate any threads"* in Java - there is no (safe way) do so, the best you can do is design for it (through `interrupt` and `isInterrupted` and or possibly internal flagging, using `AtomicBoolean` for example) - It's not confusion - it's simply a statement which is easily misinterrupted or otherwise untrue. You might be able to terminate the executor, but that just stops it from scheduling new tasks, it does not stop the currently running task.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, so you're implying that this answer may be so misconstrued that someone may think that they need to create a new _ProcessBuilder_ instance, and send over _pthread_kill_ calls?  It's much easier to presume he is talking about the _interrupt_ mechanism.  Which, is abstracted, and documented, by Oracle.

Comment: @BasilBourque, that is _clearly_ not what this answer was implying.

Comment: @Reilas No, they're not saying that. They're saying the word "(forcibly) terminate" is the wrong term to use, because it implies the thread will be killed. Assuming a beginner will interpret the word "_terminate_" as "_the thread is interrupted, and the task's code has been properly coded to respond to interrupts, allowing the task to cancel its work gracefully, **maybe** leading the death of the thread (depending on other factors)_" is, I believe, assuming too much.

Comment: @Reilas No, I'm saying you CAN NOT safely *"forcibly terminate any threads"* in Java.  A less experienced developer might be tempted to try and use `Thread#stop`, despite the fact that it's documented as "unsafe" - the wording *"forcibly terminate any threads"* is misleading

Comment: @Slaw, the answer is implying that the next step in the threading process would be to stop any running threads.  And three of you are trying to say that the terminology is incorrect.  I don't see how anyone would misunderstand what he's saying.  It's a step for a process in theory.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, it's not misleading in the context.  And, _[Thread#stop](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop())_ throws an _UnsupportedOperationException_, it's the only statement in the [method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L1666).  I don't believe a new programmer would think that is a logical approach.

Comment: @Reilas Without a runnable example to prove you're right - you're wrong. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+forcefully+terminate+thread&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=java+forcefully+terminate+thread&aqs=chrome..69i57.11219j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) seems to disagree with you to

Answer (score 0):

First read this post:

[How do I interrupt a thread given a Future object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691933/how-do-i-interrupt-a-thread-given-a-future-object/62439075#62439075)

The main thing you need to make sure of is that your threads **act responsibly** when the thread is interrupted.

In other words, your code's responsibility is to be ready for any interruptions. I'd go so far to say that whenever you have a long running task, that you insert some interrupt ready code like this:

```java
while (... something long...) {

     ... do something long

     if (Thread.interrupted()) {
         ... stop doing what I'm doing...
     }
}
```

If your code checks for `Thread.interrupted` frequently and if it handles InterruptedExceptions correctly (ie. it stops the thread loop) like this:

```
private void someMethodDeepDown() {
    while (.. long running task .. ) {
          try {
              ... do lots of work ...
    
          // or just let it propagate up!
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             // oh no! an interrupt! 
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
             throw new StopTheThreadRuntimeException(...);
          }
     }
}
```

Then that will make your threads interruptible. And then it's just a matter of tracking each thread, and when it exceeds its allotted time you can call Thread.interrupt() and it will die.

**Big Caveat**

Unfortunately, there are many libraries that don't handle InterruptedException correctly, by just suppressing it, or not checking for Thread.interrupted() in long running tasks.

So there's no guarantee your thread will die quickly unless you have full control of the thread's code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basic task, this might be a pattern you can adapt and apply to a *[ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)*.

For a comprehensive tutorial on concurrency, see the following.
[Lesson: Concurrency (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)

It involves a parent thread that will interrupt its sub-thread after a specified amount of time.

You can use the *[Thread#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long))* method to have the calling thread wait a specified amount of time before continuing its execution.

Consider the following class, *ThreadA*.
For demonstration purposes, I'm going to use *Thread#sleep* to simulate some sort of computation.

```java
class ThreadA extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("thread-A completed");
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            System.out.println("thread-A interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

In total, *ThreadA* is going to take 2 seconds to complete, printing *"thread-A completed"* to the standard-out.

From our parent thread, we can instantiate this thread, and have the parent thread wait for a specified amount of time before continuing.

We'll start the thread by calling the *[Thread#start](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start())* method.
Additionally, we'll call *Thread#join* and specify the amount of time to wait before returning, in this case *1,000* milliseconds.
Finally, upon return, we'll make a call to *[Thread#interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())*, notifying the thread to terminate its execution.

```java
ThreadA threadA = new ThreadA();
threadA.start();
threadA.join(1000);
threadA.interrupt();
System.out.println("parent thread completed");
```

Output

```
parent thread completed
thread-A interrupted
```

As an example, if we increased our *join* time to *2,500*, we'll get the following.

```
thread-A completed
parent thread completed
```

Comment: Thought experiment: replace `Thread.sleep(2000)` with an infinite loop.  Does this still work?